# IIS etags changing for no apparent reason

Tags: http, iis, iis-7.5, fiddler, etag

I've got a simple app hosted in IIS 7.5.  Using Fiddler, I am seeing that a simple refresh of my browser causes some but not all of my javascript files to be re-downloaded (status 200).  If I refresh again, sometimes they all return 304, and sometimes 200 again - the difference being that the Etag from IIS changed.  I'm the only one on this system, and the files are not changing.  Their last modified stamp in the response from the server is not changing, and yet the Etag keeps changing.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments with IIS, I've come to learn that if the file is compressed by static compression, the ETag changes. Temporarily disable static compression to check if this is your cause.